# Use Product Image as category Image in Virtuemart

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I m making a website using Joomla (2.5) and Virtuemart (2.6.14) . My question is :

Is it possible to fill category view thumbnails with a thumbnail of a product that belongs to this category? 
I dont want to upload photos to categories one by one because this would take huge amount of time.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a template override of `/components/com_virtuemart/sublayouts/categories.php` to `/templates/your_template/html/com_virtuemart/sublayouts/categories.php`.

And replace this code (approx. line: 74):

```
echo $category->images[0]->displayMediaThumb("",false);
```

With:

```
$productModel = VmModel::getModel('product');
$prod_in_category = $productModel->getProductListing(false, 1, false, true, true, true, $category->virtuemart_category_id);
$productModel->addImages($prod_in_category[0],1);
if(!empty($prod_in_category[0]->images[0])){
    echo $prod_in_category[0]->images[0]->displayMediaThumb("",false);
} else {
    echo $category->images[0]->displayMediaThumb("",false);
}
```

You could also use this method that takes a random image but it will take much more memory as it uses an array of all category products.

```
$productModel = VmModel::getModel('product');
$prod_in_category = $productModel->getProductsInCategory($category->virtuemart_category_id);
$sel = array_rand($prod_in_category);
$productModel->addImages($prod_in_category[$sel],1);
if(!empty($prod_in_category[$sel]->images[0])){
    echo $prod_in_category[$sel]->images[0]->displayMediaThumb("",false);
} else {
    echo $category->images[0]->displayMediaThumb("",false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. For the record : The correct path for the file to change was /public_html/templates/template_name/html/com_virtuemart/category/categories.php . I could not find a directory sublayouts in my system.